# ADODB Connection - Error: Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, ado

I never had problems connecting to Access DBs in the past using ODBC.  Now I am trying to connect using ADO/OLEDB and I am getting this error (DSNless connection):

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

I am no longer using ODBC.  As I said I am using ADO/OLEDB.  Here's my code:

```
var conString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=d:\\test.mdb";
// I've also tried the one below, same error
// var conString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=d:\\test.mdb";
var con = new ADODB.Connection( conString );
// bombs here
con.Open();
```

I've looked at almost everything Google and this site has regarding this error with MS Access.  I've tried changing my projects back to 32-bit (x86).  Nothing seems to work.

Anyone have any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
I need an ADODB connection because I am using ADOX which requires an ADODB connection.

```
var cat = new Catalog();
// this line below will bomb for ODBC or OLEDB
cat.ActiveConnection = con;
```

Comment: Please add code for `ADODB.Connection(string)`

Comment: Uh, I don't follow.  It's right above in the question.

Comment: You need to install OLEDB drivers for machine. from : http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: I have Office installed.  They didn't get installed with Office?

Comment: I found this problem with some machine where driver version not compatible, for creating connection.

Comment: I am starting to wonder if my problem is tied to the fact that I have Office 2013 installed.  I am unable to install the Access Database Engine 2010 SP1 because it says I don't have Access 2010.  Does Microsoft need to patch this for 2013 as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try making OLEDB connection. Also please mention the output  .

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim cnn As OleDbConnection
    connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=yourdatabasename.mdb;"
    cnn = New OleDbConnection(connetionString)
    Try
        cnn.Open()
        MsgBox("Connection Open ! ")
        cnn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Can not open connection ! ")
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

You need to provide the specific Driver Info While making the connection .Follow the Next code .

```
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim cnn As OdbcConnection
    connetionString = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=yourdatabasename.mdb;"
    cnn = New OdbcConnection(connetionString)
    Try
        cnn.Open()
        MsgBox("Connection Open ! ")
        cnn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Can not open connection ! ")
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I need to use an ADODB connection.  See my update.  I was able to connect using OLEDB but I cannot use that connection type with ADOX.

Comment: The second code is for the same.You need to specify driver while making the connnectionString else it wont work .

Comment: The code you provided is for OLEDB and ODBC.  I need an ADODB connection.  I cannot use OLEDB or ODBC with an ADOX object.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install OLEDB drivers which required to make connection:

Connection string:

`<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source d:\\test.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;" />`

Drivers can install from below link:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: After installing those drivers I get this error on the ADOX.Catalog().Create( conString ) command: An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred

Comment: This new exception not related to OLEDB connection. Please check in project `GSS.BaseballIO` by using debugging.

Comment: If I go back and create the mdb file manually and just try to connect with the ADODB.Connection, I get my original error (Data source name not found and no default driver specified).  So now I can still not connect using ADODB and now I can no longer even create a database at runtime.

Comment: Per Microsoft: "The SEHException class handles SEH errors that are thrown from unmanaged code"  All of my code is managed with the exception of what is happening within the COM.

Comment: Also, I didn't get that error until I installed the drivers you mentioned.  My code (at least for that piece) worked fine before the install of the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I was just wrestling with this problem and I found an odd solution that worked for me:

```
        // NOTE: this way doesn't work.  It throws an error:
        //  System.RuntimeInteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified at ADODB.Connection.Open
        //_connection = new Connection(_connectionString);
        //_connection.Open();

        // This way *does* work.
        _connection = new Connection();
        _connection.Open(_connectionString, null, null, 0);
```